# Case insensitive regex for non-ASCII strings does not work?

Tags: neo4j

With Neo4j 2.1.0-M01, I just discovered that case insensitive regex match does not work with Ukrainian words, at list from web-interface browser. Say I have node with a word 'Ліга' somewhere.

`MATCH (n) WHERE n.payload =~ '(?i).*ліга.*'` does not match

`MATCH (n) WHERE n.payload =~ '(?i).*лІГа.*'` does not match

`MATCH (n) WHERE n.payload =~ '(?i).*Ліга.*'` match Ok

Do I need some deep magic to get it working as expected? Thanks in advance!

WBR,
Andrii

Answer (score 4):

Not 100% sure, but could you please check if using `(?u)` helps:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.payload =~ '(?iu).*лІГа.*'
```

This tells the regex to work case insensitive based on unicode and not on ASCII only.