# How to match word in regex with non english characters in Neo4j?

Tags: regex, neo4j

I have a word, for example: Fabérgé

I'm trying to write regex to match word with non-english characters typing in regex without non-english characters.

I mean something like that:

```
[(A-Za-z)|(^\x00-\x7F)]*Faber.*
```

Should match Fabérgé but it doesn't. Don't have an idea how to do this.

Comment: What language are you using? Most languages have support for unicode regular expressions. Also, some languages have two different types for strings: byte strings and unicode strings. What kind of string are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to make query search with like in Neo4j. Don't want do this in code because i need to search on graph results and i know i can normalize name and store it as other column but this is not the correct way.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more of input and desired output ?

Comment: é is still an UTF-8 character, so you should be able to match it without using charcode like you do.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371028/case-insensitive-regex-for-non-ascii-strings-does-not-work#answer-27999092) suggests using `(?u)` for Unicode regular expressions in Neo4j. This regex should work in your case:

```
(?u)\w+
```

Note that I've used `\w`, no ranges. If you really want to use ranges, then you must use Unicode codepoints.

Comment: You mean something like: '(?iu)\\w+.*Faberge.*' ?

Comment: @DawidPR: Mh... no. Perhaps I misunderstood your question, what do you want to match exactly? A word that precedes "Faberge" (without accents)?

Comment: In graph i have field named for example "name". This name has value: "Restaurant Fabérgé". I want to write a select query that will allow me to get result "Restaurant Fabérgé" without typing this non english characters. For example: MATCH (restaurant:Restaurants) WHERE restaurant.name =~ '.*Faberge.*' should return: "Restaurant Fabérgé"

Comment: @DawidPR: if your problem is that you just want to avoid typing those characters, then just skip over them: `Fab.rg.` -- you can't type `e` and expect it to be interpreted like `é`

Comment: so in neo4j there isn't something like in sql COLLATE etc ? and with regex i can't do that ? adding a dot it's not a solution because it will return other results with Fab and rg, for example: Fabirgu will be returned for Fab.rg.

Comment: @DawidPR: POSIX regular expressions have a feature called "collating elements" (it works like this: `Fab[[=e=]]rg[[=e=]]`), but I don't know of any parser implementing them. I don't think neo4j supports them.